# Cloud vision api text detection showing syntax errors

Tags: java, java-8, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have downloaded `Java Vision API` project from [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/java/text).

I enabled billing for my project through developers console and got client_secret for my project. Later by adding an environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to my client_secret file. I'm able to do all the other operations like Labeling, face detection and Landmark detection. When I try to execute text_detection code I'm getting these errors. [See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVA6W.jpg)

```
public void indexDirectory(Path inputPath) throws IOException {
List<Path> unprocessedImages =
    Files.walk(inputPath)
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .filter(index::isDocumentUnprocessed)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
Lists.<Path>partition(unprocessedImages, BATCH_SIZE)
    .stream()
    .map(this::detectText)
    .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
    .filter(this::successfullyDetectedText)
    .map(this::extractDescriptions)
    .forEach(index::addDocument);}
```

This is the code I've written and I'm getting the below errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Files cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    Syntax error on token ":", EnhancedForStatementHeaderInit expected after this token

    at com.google.cloud.vision.samples.text.TextApp.indexDirectory(TextApp.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.vision.samples.text.TextApp.main(TextApp.java:107)
```

I know that these are syntax error but still I'm unable to find any solution to make it work.

Can anyone please suggest me how I can get this to work.

Comment: show your code as well, so others can look for the syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm new to stackoverflow @ElzoValugi